# CoAP confirmable response

Tags: coap

My server exposes a set of measurements but only those that have not been read yet.  For this purpose, I have only implemented a single resource  `/new` that discards measurements that it has just sent after a `GET` request.  How can I make the server wait for the requester to acknowledge the reception of the response?

I know this is not fully respectful of CoAP semantics but it would still be useful for me.  I mean the server would only discard readings that have actually been received by some client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably solved it (in that case could you tell which approach did you use? i am interested). Anyway i think you should use the Token (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7252#section-5.3.1). This is what i would do:

1. Client sends a CON request to server containing the message token.
2. Server sends an empty ACK with same token.
3. Server sends a CON response containing the same token and the set of measurements.
4. Client sends an empty ACK with same token.
5. Server can now delete read resources.

Comment: It is not obvious to me that CoAP allows you to do that.  A token is meant to match a response with a request, not two pairs of request-response.  In my case, I chose to make the server initiate the communication to the client with a confirmable POST request.

Comment: Differently from the message ID, which is used to uniquely identify a message and help the server in duplicate detection, Token is used to correlate messages that participate in a single set of logically related transactions, even if the message identifiers are different. You can find an example here (figure 20) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7252#page-108

Comment: I edited my answer to use a NON request by the client to minimize the exchange of messages

Comment: A token is really meant to associate a response with a request, not several such pairs.  The RFC even suggests it could be have been named "request ID" and that the client should not reuse tokens with a given server endpoint.  Of course message ID are different, they associate a CON message with its corresponding ACK.  Besides, in your 2), I think you meant response, not request.

Comment: You suggestion is valid because it solves the problem by forcing the server to send the response separately, and thus being able to make it confirmable.  I wish it could have been done with two CON messages and two ACKs, the first one being piggybacked, but this does not seem to be possible.

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding. The RFC is not clear, it states that "The client SHOULD generate tokens in such a way that tokens currently in use for a given source/destination endpoint pair are unique". It means that at any given time the CLIENT can't generate a new REQUEST with same token or it could be confused. It was introduced to manage things like Separate Responses (as this case) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7252#section-5.2.2 and the observe option. In fact as you can see in the example in the RFC from page 107, REQUESTS sent by SERVER carry the same TOKEN received from client.

Comment: I edited my answer to use 2 CON requests as you asked. As you can see in figure 20 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7252#page-108 the requests sent by the server carry the same TOKEN sent by the client.

Comment: No, I do not think the example from page 107 backs your position because the second client message is just a retransmission of the same request.  Even the message ID is identical.  Furthermore, as I said, your 3) is not a request, it is a response from the server to the client request and therefore carries the same token.  Your other explanations are correct to me.

Comment: I edited your answer accordingly, and marked it as the correct one, as it is the best we have.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, page 107 (figure 19) is just a retransmission, i wanted you to look at page 108 (figure 20 is the perfect example) and following (figure 21 and 23). And sorry for the misunderstanding with requests and responses at my 3rd step. I usually call requests CON and NON messages and responses ACK and RST messages, but it's a personal concept.

Comment: Figures 20, 21 and 23 confirm that a token enables the client to know the request a response originated from, and that it is very useful for the use cases mentioned in the RFC.  Anything I have said still seems to be correct.  To clarify the vocabulary used by the RFC: it specifies that there can be CON/NON requests as well as CON/NON responses.  A response must carry the same token as the corresponding request.  A CON message involves an ACK message carrying the same message ID as the CON message it acknowledges, be it a request or a response.

Answer (score 0):

the server could delete the resource once it was read.

you can also take a look at CoAP-MQ a draf for publish/subscribe on top of CoAP

Comment: No, being read is not enough.  The server must make sure the client has actually received the response.  Regarding CoAP-MQ, this seems to be an attractive solution but I do not think it is widely implemented.  Generally speaking, the pub/sub model such as the one of MQTT may well be more appropriate for my use case because of the QoS guarantees it can provide.

Comment: Ok I made a mistake the server plublish resources and the client consume them, once it's consumed the client must delete them.

Comment: Okay, you can do that but it involves more messages, which can cost battery for the sensor.  What I am looking for is basically a response which is both piggybacked (sent along the server's ack) and confirmable (the server will wait for the client to send an ack).  If this is impossible, your solution is an acceptable alternative though.

Comment: I think what you are looking is reliable pub/sub like MQTT